# Sampling with Rectangular Pulse and Nyquist Condition

Tags: sampling, nyquist, reconstruction

The classical Nyquist theorem assumes that the sampled signal is obtained by multiplying the signal with dirac-delta functions separated by width 1/f_sample or less. Given such sampling we can reconstruct the signal.

How does the reconstruction process change assuming that we multiply the singal with rectangular pulses spaced with the same or narrower widht than 1/f_sample? The rectangular pulses have fixed width and height and do not overlap. To obtain the discrete time series of the signal we integrate the obtained signal on each rectangular pulse.

Answer (score 0):

That is more or less what happens in a (monochrome) camera only in 2-d (or 3-d if you like).

I think you can think of it as a continuous time convolution that happens to be sampled at some multiple >= 1 times the kernel width.

Ie a sinc filter in the freq domain. As long as the main lobe is within your passband you should be able to flatten using an inverse similar to that used for the same purpose in CIC filters?

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to perfectly reconstruct the signal?

Comment: No, I think that as long as your passband is well contained within the mainlobe of the sinc, that you can compensate by a suitably chosen inverse. Provided that you can accurately characterize the system and that the SNR after filtering is withon your requirements.